Identifying transistor topology in discrete phono preamp
I try to understand how preamp of Bozak CMA-10-2DL works. Can someone please help me identify what kind of topologies transistors Q1, Q2 and Q3 are forming? Is it active or passive phono preamp? Seems like the RIAA filter is formed by C8, C9, R13, R14 and i'm not sure if it works in a feedback loop or not.


Thank you very much. And what about Q1? Is it common emiter? It's also difficult for me to tell.

Unfortunately i can't see how signal from Q1 emitter enters the base of Q3.

@cubix Q1's circuitry does the RIAA work. I'm not interested in working out the details for that aspect. So I'll ignore it. Q2 and Q3 are in class-A. You can see something similar in something I wrote here at the section subtitled: one class-A 2-quadrant approach. The output stage of your circuit is more interesting (and better) as it uses a bootstrapping C6. Q1 is in the same topology where I called it Q4 in my circuit, but it serves more purposes in your circuit (RIAA.) Q3 in my circuit is gone but C5 is the Miller cap in both cases.

I'm pretty sure that Q3 is functioning as a constant-current load for Q2. Combined with the Sziklai arrangement with Q1, this gives the circuit very high open-loop gain, which is brought under control using negative feedback through R8 (for bias) and the RIAA network (for frequency response).

@DaveTweed That's a good way to write it. Bootstrap C6 ensures fixed voltages across R10 and R11 during operation. (Just work around the KVL loops to see the constant voltages across each.) So their sum is directed to the collector of Q2. Just as you say. I'd assume an output bias point of halfway, or 20 V -- either side of R11, doesn't matter. R2 and R3 divide out to about 5.8 V so there's about 14+ V across R8 for about 80 uA, quiescent. Most of that (3/4?) should be quiescently going through R7, the rest for the base current in Q2.

@cubix In case it helps in reading the answers you already have, this re-drawn version of the schematic is how I see it.

@periblepsis wow, that's awesome! thank you

@cubix Learn to always redraw! Just get into the practice. Stuff just sorts itself as you go, especially as you train yourself over time. Glad to hear it helped out. :)

It's a mu-follower.
The terminology dates back to vacuum tube days, where the bottom triode sees a nearly infinite load resistance (thus, voltage gain equals μ of the triode), and the top triode acts as cathode follower.
Further reading: https://www.tubecad.com/2009/10/blog0173.htm
Using bipolar-junction triodes* instead, we find μ extremely high (normally expressed as Early effect), so the gain of this output stage can also be very high (thousands).
The top section (R12, R10, Q3, C6, R11) is a gyrator, an active network that effectively converts the capacitive impedance of C6 into an inductance as seen by Q2's collector.  That is, the impedance is low at DC (hence bias voltage is stable; the quiescent point is partially set by R12/R10), at some toe frequency rising ~proportional with frequency, up to some knee frequency where impedance levels off, or capacitance takes over.  Specifically: Q2 Early effect, in parallel with R12, and the loss tangent due to Q3's finite gain, sets the maximum/peak impedance.
Q3 also acts as an emitter follower, hence the output has low impedance.  Indeed, it's intentionally set to 1k with R15.
The output stage's high gain is tempered by feedback to the input stage, a simple common-emitter amplifier: notice the low value of R6, making it AC-common, with C4's large value ensuring this is true over the audio range.  Curiously, Q1's bias current is minuscule: supplied only through R8 (180k).  Q1's quiescent point is set by R3/R2.  The high gain and modest feedback ratio affords room for a filter network -- indeed, C8, C9, R13 and R14 form a phono compensation network.
Finally, that leaves R8/R7, together with R12/R10, setting the overall voltage bias condition.  I would expect the circuit to drift quite a bit (100s mV?) as it warms up, or as components age; since it's AC-coupled, this is quite tolerable.  The biggest downside I would say, is because it's an AC-coupled single-supply design, there's a big turn-on "pop" as everything settles out (and this is quite significant, coming from a 40V supply, of which about half might be used i.e. 20V output bias).
*Past the 1960s or so, authors stopped referring to them by electrode number, and more by category: "transistor" generically for BJTs (still in common use today), and other types as such ("thyristor", "FET", etc.).  Today, you most often see "triode" (referring to transistors) as a (minor or archaic) translation error from Chinese, where (I guess) the terminology stuck.  The unit in question was released 1971-ish, I gather? So this would've been archaic terminology by then as well.

Yes, the unit was made in 70s.
If Q1 is a common emitter amp why does its collector connects to ground via a resistor? It should go to VCC, right?
I really appreciate your detailed explanation, but could you please give me some hints to understand the role of Q2? Thank you!

Q1 is CE by application of the principle of an AC equivalent circuit.  Q2 as well (more literally so, given the small resistor E to GND).

@TimWilliams  That's a great link to Tubecad, I will enjoy reading that, cheers.

Here is your circuit, for reference in this answer. It is also a working model that can be used for simulation.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Can someone please help me identify what kind of topologies transistors Q1, Q2 and Q3 are forming?

Q2 and Q3 form a Shunt Regulated Push-Pull (SRPP) amplifier (which seems to also go by the name of mu-follower per Tim Williams' answer). The workings of an SRPP amplifier will be discussed below.
Q1, with it's base considered as input is a PNP common emitter amplifier. (The collector resistor is R7). With Q1's emitter considered as input, it is a common base amplifier. It serves both as an amplifier, and as a feedback junction point between the over-all circuit input, and feedback coming from the emitter of Q3. One might think of Q1 and a sort of differential amplifier with a very large (i.e. \$\approx\$ 0.7 V) input offset voltage.

Is it active or passive phono preamp?

Active. It uses power from a separate rail different from the output line.

Seems like the RIAA filter is formed by C8, C9, R13, R14

Yes.

i'm not sure if it works in a feedback loop or not.

Yes. There is a feedback loop.
The input signal enters the loop at the base of Q1. Travels from the collector of Q1 to the base of Q2. It goes from the collector of Q2 through C6 to the base of Q3, and is both output from the loop at the emitter of Q3, and also fed back from the emitter of Q3 to the emitter of Q1.
SRPP
Here is the Shunt Regulated Push-Pull section of your circuit. (The biasing of the base of Q2 has been hidden within the input current source.)

simulate this circuit
R10 and R12 are a voltage divider used to keep C6 charged (and consequently the base of Q3 biased). C6 is sufficiently large for the voltage across it to be essentially constant at audio frequencies. Since the voltage across C6 is equal to the Vbe of Q3 plus the voltage across R11, the voltage across R11 (and consequently the current through it) will be essentially constant.
Since the current through R11 is essentially constant, so is Q2's collector current. This gives Q2 a quite high voltage gain.
At the same time, since the voltage across R11 and Q3's Vbe are essentially constant, the output can draw greater or lesser current from the emitter of Q3 without loading Q2. That is, Q2 maintains its high voltage gain independently of output loading. If the emitter of Q3 had been merely been the output of a constant current source, then the impedance seen by the collector of Q2 would have been the impedance value of that constant current source in parallel with the impedance of the output load. In most cases, that would be approximately the impedance of the output load. A high output load (that is low output load impedance) would lower impedance seen by the collector of Q2, and hence lower Q2's voltage gain. The SRPP configuration isolates the high voltage gain of Q2 from output loading. That is the "value added" by the SRPP configuration compared to using a simple current source as an active load.

Most of the filtering that taylors the frequency response is around a feedback network so the RIAA equalisation is active .The npn output scheme runs class A for low distortion .This also gives voltage gain keeping component count low .The seemingly high 40Volt supply gives good overload performance .Such a single supply was readily available in power amplifiers of this vintage.
